# stopping postman after request is done

Tags: node.js, rest, routes, postman

I am trying to create a Weather API using node. In my controller file, I have this code which is run for the /check route.

controller.js:

```
//Check Weather
exports.check = (req, res) => {
    UserModel.check(req.body.city)
};
```

model.js:

```
//Check Weather
function getData(city) { 

url = "something";
request(url, function (err, response, body) {
if(err){
    console.log('error:', error);
} else {
    console.log('body:', body);
}
});
} 

exports.check = (city) => {

city = city.toLowerCase();
let values = getData(city);
console.log(city);

return(values);
};
```

route:

```
app.post('/check', [
    UsersController.check
]);
```

When I run this, it functions properly and the correct thing is logged in the console. However, after I send a request in Postman and the console.log shows up, Postman seems to be hung up as seen in this pic[image: Postman]. Is there anyway I can make it so that Postman stops sending the request after return or console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman is waiting for a response from the server. Your code is not currently sending any response, so postman seems 'hung up' as it is waiting. Try changing the line saying `UserModel.check(req.body.city)` to say `res.send(UserModel.check(req.body.city))` so it will send the data returned from your `UserModel.check` function back as the response. Alternatively, if you don't want to send back the returned value, you could just add `res.send(PutWhateverYouWantSentHere)` after the function call.